# jQuery Undefined error when trying to get only <option> element

Tags: jquery

I have html with a `<select>` tag and `<option>` tags. I get a certain option / value in this way:

```
$(targetElement).children("option[text=" + Text + "]").val();
```

where `targetElement` is my `<select>` element and `Text` is the text of the option I want to find.

This works fine when there are multiple options in the `select` ([on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dbQ7m/1/)), but when there is only one option, I get `undefined` ([on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aBWE5/))!

Can anyone tell me why it doesn't work when there is only one option, and how I can fix it?

Comment: Could you provide sample input and value of Text?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
  var lastOptionValue = $('select > option:last').val();
  alert(lastOptionValue);
});
```

You can try [here](http://jsbin.com/oyozez/edit#javascript,html).

**EDIT:**
Sorry, I was unattentive...

This is your [correct example](http://jsbin.com/omomow/2/edit#source):

```
$(function(){
  text = 'Foo';
  var $last = $('select>option').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() == text;
  }).last();
  if ($last.length > 0){
    alert($last.val());
  }
});
```

You can add more functionality in `filter()` anonymous function. For example RegExp or something else what you need.

Answer (score 2):

[`[name=value]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) syntax is meant to check the attributes of an element. For example, it would be used to match FooInAttribute but not FooInContents below.

```
<option value="42" text="FooInAttribute">FooInContents</option>
```

I can't tell you why it works when there are multiple `<option>` tags available, but [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) works in both scenarios. Try this instead, but as InviS notes, this  assumes that no option in the list contains the full text of another (i.e., if you have an option called 'Burger', you must not have another 'Burger and Fries'):

```
$(targetElement).children("option:contains('" + text + "')").val();
```

Comment: contains is not correct, I think. He can get extra options. For example, if text will be `SomeFooSome` or `...Foo...` and he will look for Foo only.

Comment: That's a good point. This solution assumes the options in the list are unique and that none of them contain the full text of another.

Comment: I agree with this answer. It's simple, but works. :) For more complex comparisons author can use my example :) Both of answers works well. Main error is incorrect usage of jQuery syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You could also make use of the `.filter()` method:

```
var txt = "Bar";
var x = $('select').children().filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == txt;
}).val();
console.log(x);
```

This will return the one value with 'Bar' as it's text.

Comment: Good point :) It's time to do coffee-break for me :D I have edited my post :)